# Bootstrap Image Between Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What would be the best / correct method to replicate the following using bootstrap. There are four colum, each of which is 25% wide, and I would like to add an image inbetween. The columns remain 25% all the way from mobile to desktop.

[image]

Comment: But if the columns are each `25%` wide, there won't be space between them for an image?

Comment: I thought perhaps there might be an available bootstrap class that may take care of it. I also thought of perhaps using :after / :before / position absolute. Just wanted to make sure there was not something obvious I was missing.

Comment: You need to use nested grid structures. Inserting content between columns is asking for a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left">
      <div class"col-xs-10">
        <img src="envelop.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class"col-xs-2 text-center">
        <img src="plus.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left">
      <div class"col-xs-10">
        <img src="envelop.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class"col-xs-2 text-center">
        <img src="plus.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left">
      <div class"col-xs-10">
        <img src="envelop.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class"col-xs-2 text-center">
        <img src="plus.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left">
      <div class"col-xs-10">
        <img src="envelop.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>
      <div class"col-xs-2 text-center">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: You may use text or content for `+` sign ... its upto you !! I prefer text/content because it will render faster then image.

Comment: This is close, but it will leave things off-center.

Comment: The columns don't render side-by-side for me when using this example. Try to put this into a JSFiddle or Bootply to see how it works live vs in theory.

Comment: You're still missing `.row` elements between your `.col-` elements.

Comment: @TimLewis just add `.pull-left` class on each image's parent `div`. And test it using real images

Comment: It's your answer. I'm just pointing out what you need to add to make it correct. If you want me to take the credit, then I can do that too :P

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job, though it's a bit convoluted. The 15-column layout is tricky.

```
.row.shift-left {
    margin-left: -20px;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="row shift-left">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">Words words words.</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x800" class="img-responsive" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7rmn83gj/)**